# How can I make Android apps that work with Apple Airplay?

Tags: android, sdk, airplay

I've read an article about Apple Airplay, and I've searched some apps like [Air bubble](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.airbubble&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5idWJibGVzb2Z0LmFuZHJvaWQuYWlyYnViYmxlIl0.), but still I have some questions:

1. Is it OK to make Airplay apps for non-iOS? Is there a license problem?
2. Does Apple's MFI program (or developer license) cover Android/Windows OS?
3. Is there some Airplay SDK for Android?
4. If not, what should I study to make Airplay receiver/sender application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469242/implement-airplay-software-receiver-in-android-os/20536343#20536343