# Implement Airplay Software Receiver in Android OS

Tags: android, airplay

Can we develop any app in Android which will play a role of Airplay Receiver? Following provides support for MAC and Windows desktop version now.

http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

I found a similar question with no reply. [How can I make Android apps that work with Apple Airplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472238/how-can-i-make-android-apps-working-with-apple-airplay).

ALSO: I have found lots of apps on Play Store performing this functionality. http://www.knowyourmobile.com/android-apps/18049/best-airplay-apps-android-gettin-dream-stream

I have found http://bubbleguuum.free.fr/airbubble/shairport/, but I am facing issue in integrating openssl in my project to link these files in NDK.

I highly appreciate any help in this direction from anybody.

Comment: Look this the cyano guys are working in this feature.. so i believe it's possible  http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/21/airplay-mirroring-android-cyanogenmod/

Comment: try to use ffmpeg for live streaming of videos

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, thanks for ur input. I am looking for pairing of devices first. How can I notify other devices about my existence?

Comment: using bluetooth or wifi o-O?

Comment: @KanakSony : I have used shareport library for that. some how I was able to manage sound and images but I dont think that was so successful for me :)

Comment: @V-Xtreme Can u help me in achieving same or share me source? It can help me.

Comment: @KanakSony:sorry to say but for some reason I dont have source code now . But I will try it out again if I get some time .

Comment: @KanakSony : Its fine :). But I have to rewind those things again.So I think it would be nice if we talk after that .probably later today .

Comment: Closing this question, as did not got any good attention here.. but, for them interesting in knowing that if we got success or not, than Yes, we got success :)

Comment: hey @KanakSony need your help how you got it working please help me i’ll be very greatful.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for Phone Application.

**DroidAirPlay** in GitHub gives support for Tablets.

Have a look.

https://github.com/pentateu/DroidAirPlay

Comment: I have got success in compiling and running this code, but facing issue of delay in buffering of audio streams, which causes in failure to play it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the guys at Cyanogenmod were able to implement this as part of of their Android fork: https://plus.google.com/110558071969009568835/posts/bsdm8BgVh2L

Wondering where the implementation lives exactly as it seems they have both an AirPlay server and a client in there to stream to another AirPlay server on the same network.

Comment: Hey, I am looking for Mirroring with Airplay. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough one, I've spent a good 3 months researching the topic and ended up implementing a prototype by reusing a piece from another app. The key challenge here is the FairPlay decryption of the challenges and keys. See my question/comments on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/airplay-mirroring-decryption-fairplay