# Get String from the text box and apply to string properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added one text box . I am getting the text entered text box like :

```
 var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
```

then by using split function I am getting one particular String from say first string from the text . And tried to apply string properly on  that like :

```
 var split = text.split(" ");
 var word = split[0];
 word.italics();
```

then I formed text again with changed properties of first string and reassigned it to the text box

```
document.getElementById("textarea").value = text;
```

but those string properties are not applying to the word . same issue with all string properties like font color ,link etc . I dont know whats wrong I am doing ?

Comment: You cannot format text in a textbox

Comment: @V-Xtreme Hi, I know its not a place to ping you. But, I m really stuck with something on which you have worked earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469242/implement-airplay-software-receiver-in-android-os?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot format text in a textbox

Try

```
document.getElementById("someContainerLikeADivOrSpan").innerHTML=text
```

For example

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3hsCK/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("text").onkeyup=function() {
    var text = this.value;
    var split = text.split(" ");
    var word = split[0];
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=word.italics();
  }
}
```

using

```
<textarea id="text" placeholder="type some words"></textarea>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `div,span or p element` to get the `italics word`. Try this,

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textarea">test the italics now.</textarea>
<div id="div"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
text=text.replace(word,word.italics());// replace the first word with italics
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = text;// use div not textarea
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jA884/)